# how to capture form data in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

How do I capture form data in Angularjs controller. I tried $scope.txn_filter_form but it is undefined in controller.

Actually I want to capture form data is same format as it get build when submit button is clicked and form tag has method=post and action="some-class".

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="post_Txn_Filter()" ng-model="txn_filter_form">     
 <input class="form-control" size="15" type="text" maxlength="13" name="txt_beg_trans_id" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.fromTransId">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" size="15" maxlength="13" name="txt_end_trans_id" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.toTransId">
 <INPUT size="2" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" name="txt_b_month" value=""  data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.begMonth">
  <INPUT size="2" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" name="txt_b_date" value="" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.begDate">
  <INPUT size="4"  class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="4" name="txt_b_year" value="" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.begYear">
 <INPUT size="2" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" name="txt_e_month" value="" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.endMonth">
  <INPUT size="2"  class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" name="txt_e_date" value="" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.endDate">
  <INPUT size="4"  class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="4" name="txt_e_year" value="" data-ng-model="form_Trx_Filter.endYear">
```

controller Code :

```
var app = angular.module('mainapp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);
app.controller('transcations',['$scope','dataFactory','enhancefil',
    function($scope,dataFactory,enhancefil) {   

        /* make post request */     
        $scope.post_Txn_Filter  =   function () { 
                tab     = 'trans/fil';
                func    = 'set';
                data    = $scope.txn_filter_form;   
                dataFactory.post_Trans(tab,func,data)
                           .then(function(httpResult) {
                           $scope.trans         = httpResult.data;  
                           });
        };


}]);

app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http','$templateCache',function($http,$templateCache) {

    var urlBase = 'resource/';
    var dataFactory = {};
    var httpResult = {data:"",status:""};

    var handleSuccess = 
        function(data, status) {
            httpResult.data = data;
            httpResult.status =  status;

        };

    var handleError = 
        function(data, status) {
            httpResult.data = data;
            httpResult.status =  status;
        };

    /* post request */
    dataFactory.post_Trans = function(tab,func,data){

        return $http.post(urlBase + tab + '/' + func,data)
            .success (handleSuccess)
                    .error(handleError);                            
    };

    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: can you share the code in your controller ?

Comment: you should add $scope to your controller. And aside from that, at what point do you want to get this data ? you can set a $watch listener for your  models ... or attach a function to the submit button, and then get the data with $scope.form_Trx_Filter.fromTransId for example

Comment: added controller code.  $scope.form_Trx_Filter is available in controller but it is object format. I cannot use it directly. code on server can process standard header format like.       txt_beg_trans_id=123456&txt_end_trans_id=999999999&txt_b_month=&txt_b_date=&txt_b_year=&txt_e_month=&txt_e_date=&txt_e_year=&

Comment: your forms model is txn_filter_form... your fields models should be txn_filter_form.fromTransId